# How to capture onClick event on react-paypal-button-v2

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am using react-paypal-button-v2 for paypal payment in react app. I would like to get the onclick event ( to disable some other options in my app during the payment process). Is there a way to do that? I tried the below code with createOrder, but it returns error

```
import { PayPalButton } from 'react-paypal-button-v2'
              <PayPalButton
              amount={survey.cost}
              onSuccess={successPaymentHandler}
              onCancel={handleIncompletePayPalProcess}
              createOrder={() => console.log('onclick triggered')}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createOrder, if implemented, needs to either return an Order ID/token from an API call, or use actions.order.create().

You are looking for... `onClick`. See [the SDK reference.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#oninitonclick)

---

react-paypal-button-v2 is not an official module; consider using the new [react-paypal-js](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-paypalbuttons--default) instead.

Comment: Thank You. what is the npm package name for official version ? is it paypal-button-react ??

Comment: ... react-paypal-js